# how can i send 2 id or more on this function by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

how can i send 2 id or more on this function by ajax

```
function advcust(id) {                      
    $.ajax ({
           url: "php_filter.php?cust=advcust",
           type: "GET",
           data: {CustStatus:id},
           success: function(data){
                    $("#return").html(data)
                    }
        })
}
```

here i can send only one id 
but i need sent 2 or more id

and i have two input type to search two words
can i send 2 id on ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function advcust(ids) {
    $.ajax ({
        url: "php_filter.php?cust=advcust",
        type: "GET",
        data: {CustStatus: ids},
        success: function(data){
            $("#return").html(data);
        }
    });
}

var ids = [];
ids.push(id1);
ids.push(id2);
advcust(ids);
```

You can then access customer IDs in PHP as an array:

```
<?php

$customerIds = $_GET['CustStatus'];

foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: ok but how can i call this function on button , i can call function on one input type but i have 2 input type

Comment: By calling `advcust()` with the relavant IDs on the `click` event.

Answer (score 2):

```
function advcust(id, anotherID)
{
  $.ajax ({
       url: "php_filter.php?cust=advcust",
       type: "GET",
       data: {CustStatus:id,SomeOverVar:anotherID},
       success: function(data){
                $("#return").html(data)
                }
    })
}
```

Comment: i will try this but i canot get value of element id why !!